# Gerrit label scoring

Tags: git, gerrit

I have created a label for my project. 
A jenkins job post scores on this label.

But now the jenkins job is failing (because for the label is not added in the access list ) and to fix it i need to change the project.config

Now if i go and change the project config. I have to submit the project.config but due to the label which i had setup earlier the change is not going in.

The gerrit ui is giving needs "label" .
But only the jenkins job can post scores in the label but it is failing.

So now i am in a deadlock in order to fix the jenkins job i have to change project.config and project.config can not be changed since the label can be posted by the jenkins job.

Is there any way to skip the label scoring ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the project config changes straight to the branch (without Code Review). You can easily do that using the Gerrit UI at:

https://gerrit.cpqd.com.br/#/admin/projects/project-pathname,access

At the end click on "Save Changes" instead of "Save for Review".

If you don't have permission to change the project config then you need to ask to the Gerrit admin.